# Displaying hebrew text on screen

Tags: matlab, text, character-encoding, fonts, hebrew

I want to display hebrew text on the screen using the [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command in MATLAB:

```
text(0.6, 0.5, 'ירוק', 'rotation', 180, 'fontsize', 50, 'color', 'r')
```

The problem is that it displays gibberish.

Does anybody know why? What should I do in order to display the text correctly?

Comment: It might well be an encoding problem - the "gibberish" you're seeing may be a result of Matlab interpreting the file as using a different character set to what you've saved it as. What exactly did get displayed? Was it: ï»¿ ×™×¨×•×§ or something similar?

Comment: ... and if they don't, then add comments and/or update your question with the extra information describing why they're no good :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a font that supports Hebrew characters - the default font (Helvetica) does not. You can use 'Courier', David' etc. For example:

```
text(0.6,0.5,'ירוק','fontname','david','rotation',180,'fontsize',50,'color','r')
```

בהצלחה!