# hebrew in the command line - matlab

Tags: string, matlab, unicode, hebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [text('hebrew string') matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639975/texthebrew-string-matlab)

shalom
I am trying to work with hebrew strings in matlab. but when I am trying to assign hebrew string to a variable, it doens't assign it. for example:

> > a='א'
> >
> > a =

any ideas why?

Comment: By the way, the answer in that post, which is to call `text(0.6,0.5,'ירוק','fontname','david','rotation',180,'fontsize',50,'color','r')` produces only boxes on my machine, and not Hebrew, probably because I don't have Hebrew characters set up on mine.

Comment: you might also find this useful: [MATLAB: how to display UTF-8-encoded text read from file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aleph is in UTF-16](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05d0/index.htm), which matlab represents with its standard 2 byte `char` format. It probably doesn't support input of it this way.

You probably have to do

```
 a = char(1488);  % 1488 is UTF-16 for aleph
```

And then output it some way readable by UTF-16.

If you're trying to simply put Hebrew into a figure title or something, then you can directly write Latex like this:

```
 title('\aleph')
```

If you are trying use Matlab for text processing, I think it will work but you might not be able to view the characters in the Matlab command window.

Update:  On my system even writing to a file in the Hebrew encoding is not supported:

```
 fid = fopen('c:\temp\chris.txt','w','native','hebrew');
 Warning: The encoding 'ISO-8859-8' is not supported.
 See the documentation for FOPEN.
```

But maybe your machine supports it if you have Hebrew languages set up.

Comment: I didn't recieve any error, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do to read/write to files in this case:

```
%# some Hebrew characters
hebrewString = repmat(char(1488),1,10);      %# 'אאאאאאאאאא'

%# convert and write as bytes
b = unicode2native(hebrewString,'UTF-8');
fid = fopen('file.txt','wb');
fwrite(fid, b, '*uint8');
fclose(fid);

%# read bytes and convert back to Unicode string
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'rb');
b = fread(fid, '*uint8')';          %'
fclose(fid);
str = native2unicode(b,'UTF-8');

%# compare and check
isequal(str,hebrewString)
double(str)
```

For displaying this string, we need to make MATLAB aware of Unicode characters by calling:

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8');
```

Now on the command prompt you can try:

```
>> str
str =
אאאאאאאאאא
```

However, displaying the string with the [TEXT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) function failed *(Can someone confirm if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639975/texthebrew-string-matlab/4641230#4641230) actually works as claimed?)*:

```
hTxt = text(0.1,0.5, str, 'FontName','David', 'FontSize',30);
set(hTxt, uisetfont(hTxt))
```

[image: TEXT]

I even checked that the correct fonts are available:

```
>> fontsNames = fontinfo();
>> idx = ~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(lower(fontsNames),'david'));
>> fontsNames(idx)'
ans = 
    'David'
    'David Bold'
    'David Regular'
    'David Transparent'
```

On the other hand, and as I showed in a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file/6872642#6872642), the solution to showing this text in a GUI is to use Java (MATLAB [UICONTROL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol.html) is based on Java Swing components):

```
figure('Position',[300 300 500 50]), drawnow
uicontrol('Style','text', 'String',str, ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1], ...
    'FontName','David', 'FontSize',30);
```

[image: UICONTROL]

(note that by using UICONTROL, even the regular 'Arial' font shows the correct output!)