# How should I setup MATLAB for correct display of Russian (Cyrillic) characters on figures in Linux?

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, cyrillic

I have installed MATLAB R2008b on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and Windows XP.
The system locale in Ubuntu is Unicode - en_US.UTF-8.

For compatibility with Windows I launch MATLAB in Ubuntu with ru_RU.CP1251 locale - so I have simple script to launch MATLAB:

```
 cat /opt/MATLAB_R2008b/bin/matlab-run
 #!/bin/bash
 export LANG="ru_RU.CP1251";
 export LC_ALL="ru_RU.CP1251";
 /opt/MATLAB_R2008b/bin/matlab -desktop
```

After that **slCharacterEncoding** and **feature('DefaultCharacterSet')** returns desired windows-1251 as expected.

There are many fonts in my system, almost all support Russian (Cyrillic) glyphs.
Russian text displays normally in **uicontrol** (see screenshot [image] )

```
uicontrol('String','Русский=Russian','Position',[0 0 200 200])
```

but does not in figure labels and title, so

```
 x = linspace(0,2*pi,100); y = sin(x);
 xlabel('x, в радианах','interpreter','none');
 ylabel('y, значение sin(x)','interpreter','none');
 title('y, значение sin(x)','interpreter','none');
```

produce wrong characters in labels and title [image: see screenshot].

I have no idea how to fix this. 
How should I setup MATLAB for correct display of Russian (Cyrillic) characters on figures in Linux?

Comment: My question looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539088/matlab-in-linux-ubuntu-11-10-doesnt-display-unicode-hebrew-in-plot-figure, but I use CP-1251 instead of Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I installed all recommended fonts - packages `xfonts-100dpi`, `xfonts-75dpi`, `xfonts-cyrillic`, `t1-cyrillic`, `cm-super`, `ttf-freefont`, `gsfonts-x11`.

But what is interesting these fonts work only for UTF-8, so I can use the following fonts for displaying Russian (Cyrillic) text in figures:

- clean
- free avant garde
- free bookman
- free chancery
- free courier
- free helvetian
- free paladin
- free schoolbook
- free times
- oldslavic
- tahoma guap
- teams
- terminus

For my original problem I found special [ttf-font file](http://goo.gl/9sVyAb), which works as expected and Russian (Cyrillic) text looks as expected in CP/Windows-1251 charset.[image: screenshot]

I placed this font in `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype`, ran `mkfontscale`, `mkfontdir` and `fc-cache -vf` and added this location to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
    Section "Files"
        FontPath "/usr/share/fonts/truetype"
        FontPath "/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype"
    EndSection
```

.

I installed `language-pack-ru` and edited  `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` as follows:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
ru_RU ISO-8859-5
ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251
ru_RU.KOI8-R KOI8-R
```

Comment: Small comment - it seems that for normal cyrillic display font must support ISO-8859-5, not CP/Windows-1251.